# Display results of all promises with order

Tags: javascript, promise, lodash

I am new to promises.

I encountered a case where I have to loop through a series of tasks and get data. For some reason I have to do it in order and have to do it using promises. But to my surprise, the result only has the last element instead of all elements.

The simplified version of code

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const test = (name) => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //This is simplified from my actual code
    resolve(name);
  });
};

const testAll = (arr) => {
  //This chains and returns a series of functions with the order of arr, so that the can be executed in the order, not simultaneously
  let functions = _.map(arr, element => test.bind(null, element));
  //This reduces the functions and is supposed to return an array of all values
  return functions.reduce((fun1, fun2) => fun1.then(fun2), Promise.resolve([]));
}

const arr = ['promise1', 'promise2', 'promise3'];

testAll(arr)
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

I was expecting the output to be (with order):

```
promise1 
promise2
promise3
```

but what I really got was just `promise3`. Is it because the `Promise.resolve([])` does not include every element in an array?

Comment: Is it needed that the promises have to be created one after the other (once the previous one resolved)? If there is no dependency then `Promise.all` is the better way...

Comment: AFAICT, everything you wrote compresses to `Promise.all(arr.map(x => () => Promise.resolve([]))).then(console.log);`

Comment: @trincot yes for some reason I have to do it one by one, as I was making http requests and making them all at the same time ('promise.all') will take down the server.

Comment: Note that a `then` only executes its callback *once* (this is a key property of promises). So you cannot get 3 different calls in your final callback. You *could* however get an array of results.

Comment: @JaredSmith wouldn't that still executes the 3 `test` functions all at the same time, if the actual content of `test` is async?

Comment: @jsh6303 in that case `arr.reduce((p, n) => p.then(_ => Promise.resolve(console.log(n))), Promise.resolve())`;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to want to accumulate the individual results into an array. For that you must at least capture the resolved value from *each* of the promises. When you do `fun1.then(fun2)` you throw away the value promised by `fun1`. To use it, you need to do something with the argument that is passed to the `then` callback. In your case you want to concatenate that with the promised value of `fun2()`.

But since you have the first, but must still wait for the second, you could benefit from `Promise.all`, like this:

```
const testAll = (arr) => {
  let functions = arr.map(element => test.bind(null, element));
  return functions.reduce((prom, fun) => 
      prom.then(data => Promise.all(data.concat(fun())) ),
      Promise.resolve([])
  );
}
```

Now your final call to `testAll` will give you an array as result.

```js
const test = (name) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(_ => { // Introduce delay for better demo
            console.log('.'); // a little trace in the output
            resolve(name); 
        }, 500);
    });
};

const testAll = (arr) => {
  let functions = arr.map(element => test.bind(null, element));
  return functions.reduce((prom, fun) => 
      prom.then(data => Promise.all(data.concat(fun())) ),
      Promise.resolve([])
  );
}

const arr = ['promise1', 'promise2', 'promise3'];

testAll(arr).then(data => console.log(data));
```